# trying to use lldb to debug c++ on vsCode on macbook

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, lldb, vscode-debugger

I am using the Microsoft's C/C++ extension in VS Code and I created a launch.json for debugging.

```
{
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "c++ Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${workspaceRoot}/main",
        "args": ["world/moveleft.w"],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "lldb"
    }
]
}
```

It does run successfully, but it doesn't stop on my breakpoints.
I am using a macbook, I tried using gdb instead of lldb and it didn't work.

Comment: at a guess you haven't compiled your code with debugging information. Please show a [mre]

Comment: yes you were right @AlanBirtles . In my make file, I added -g to COMPILERFLAGS and that solved the issue. thanks

Answer (score 1):

@mvoelcker's comment about adding `-g` is super helpful.